# Global sections of twisted dualizing sheaf of Hirzebruch surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let consider a Hirzebruch surface $S= \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ over $\mathbb{P}^1$ with invariant $e \ge 0$ where $\mathcal{E}= \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(e) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$.

Let $\omega_S$ be the dualizing sheaf of $S$. One knows that for $n \ge 1$ 
$$h^0(\omega_S^{\otimes n})= dim_k H^0(S,\omega_S^{\otimes n})=0 $$

What about $h^0(\omega_S^{\otimes -n})$? How can I calculate them?

Comment: you can just write down $\omega_S^{\otimes -n}$ and pushdown to $\mathbb{P}^1$ to calculate the global sections.

Comment: You mean using projection formula?

Comment: Yes, you just need to compute the global section of a symmetric product of a rank two vector bundle twisted by some line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$. On the other hand, if you know some basic knowledge of  toric varieties, you can compute the global sections by counting points.